# Windows 2019 IIS webserver redirect

Tags: iis, subdomain, windows-server-2019

I have 1 IIS web server (Main) and 5 other IIS web servers behind it (1-5). The applications are all different and there are 125 of them. They are split up between the 5 servers. I'm wanting to use a wildcard cert and use sub domains for the different applications to keep them separate.

Is it possible to have the main web servers web page have links that are all the different sub-domain URL's?

When you click on one, the main IIS web server would then redirect it to the correct server behind it. That server would use host name bindings to deliver the site.

Due to high traffic I want to distribute the applications across multiple servers. Or is there a better way to handle the sub domains from a single web page to multiple IIS servers?

Everything I have researched so far are rewrites and redirects on the same IIS server.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reverse proxy: something that can act a front end for all your web sites and can contact the correct server for the requested URL.

There are lots of reverse proxy solutions around; if you want to do this with a Windows server, have a look at [Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing).

Comment: Ok I thought it was more for server farms serving the same content. So the setup would be the web server then the  ARR server and then the application servers? Or ARR server hosting the website then the applications servers behind it?

Comment: A server with ARR (which works on top of IIS) receives requests from clients and then calls the internal server which actually hosts the web site.

Comment: But you only need this if the internal servers are not directly reachable from the Internet; otherwise, you can just set up your DNS to map each site name to the server that is hosting it.

Comment: To clarify: if you have a single IP and you want to publish `sitea.domain.com` and `siteb.domain.com`, you map the names in DNS to the IP of the ARR server, and then configure the ARR server to call internal server A  for `sitea.domain.com` and internal server B for `siteb.domain.com`; but if you have instead an IP for each server, you only need to map each name to the correct IP and the clients will directly call the servers.